# Razor Markdown based on DTO type not using _Layout.cshtml

Tags: razor, markdown, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack Markdown Razor to render a DTO, but it is not using _Layout.cshtml. I am following the convention wherein the name of the Markdown file is the same as the response type.

My source tree looks like this:

```
Services/
    ExampleService.cs
Transfer/
    Example.cs
Views/
    Shared/
        _Layout.cshtml
    Example.md
```

**ExampleService.cs**

```
public class ExampleService : IService
{
    public Example Get(ExampleRequest request)
    {
        return new Example { Greeting = "Hello, MD!" };
    }
}
```

Thus, if I visit `.../html/reply/ExampleRequest` I see the rendered Markdown which has access to the `@Model`. But, it does not use the available _Layout.cshtml (even if I move it to the same directory).

Is this supported? If so, how is it configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Automatically use the nearest _Layout.cshtml**

I can't tell if this is supported any longer. It appears that /Views/Shared/_Layout.shtml is the file to use as your default template. The other option to define a layout/template page is to use the @Layout or @template syntax as you noted above.

**@RenderBody() is not supported,**

Correct. This is intentional as noted [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Markdown-Razor#layoutmasterpage-scenarios---the-basics)

*Rather then using a magic method like @RenderBody() we treat the output Body of View as just another variable storing the output a in a variable called 'Body'.*

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the Markdown file include an **@Layout** directive.

Also, in the _Layout.cshtml file use `<!--@Body-->` instead of `@RenderBody()`. This is shown below and described on the [Markdown Features](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/markdown/markdown-razor) page under the section "Layout/MasterPage Scenarios - The Basics".

**Example.md**

```
@Layout Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

## @Model.Greeting
It is the year @DateTime.Now.Year
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Markdown Razor Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--@Body-->
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Editorial**

That said, this approach is undesirable because it deviates from the two relevant conventions used in the [RazorRockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars) example:

1. Automatically use the nearest _Layout.cshtml
2. @RenderBody() is not supported, and using @Body causes a startup error when trying to compile _Layout.cshtml early.

Comment: Can you use default.shtml (with same contents as _Layout.cshtml) instead of _Layout.cshtml to avoid the startup error?

Comment: Yes, because the layout is being specified explicitly, it could be named anything... So, you are right, that would mitigate the error. Alas, that would be one more convention ignored.